# How to plot both log scale in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the below equation vs frequency in both log scale using the `loglog()` function on the x and y axes.

```
c_lead = 0.4018e-12;
l_lead = 43.333e-9;
wc = 2.488e+10;
R = 100;
w = 10000:10:1000000000;

x = ((w./wc).^2)./((w.*c_lead).*(1+((w./wc).^2)));
Zab = R./(1+((w./wc).^2)) + (w.*l_lead - x)*1i;
loglog(w, (abs(Zab)));
title('R = 100ohm');
xlabel('Frequency (in Hz)','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color','r');
ylabel('Impedance (in ohm)','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color','r');
grid on;
```

However, as you can see, there is no log scale effect on the y axis. How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With so small a range on the Y axis, the log and linear scales will be almost indistinguishable. Does MATLAB default to showing a linear scale in this case, even with your loglog() call? Try plotting Zab=w, to get a large range on Y axis, to see if it changes. Did you want to plot the log of (Zab-100), that will have a larger range!

Answer (score 0):

`w = 10000:10:1000000000;` specifies a range of 1e4 to 1e9. Do you want the range to be 1e4 to 1e10 as shown in your graph? This will cause the y data to go from 100 to about 400.

Since the y-range is limited to 100 to about 107 with your specification of the w-range, the y-axis may well be log scaled, but the range is so small that log scale and linear scale will look about the same. Measuring the intervals on the y-axis shows they have a slightly different pixel interval which means log scaled.

Comment: I fixed it using logspace() and yLim[] function. Thanks.